# Laravel 5.2 Authentication redirect works in Dev, not Prod

Tags: redirect, laravel-5, laravel-forge

I'm finding a strange problem that only shows up in production, not dev.  My Laravel dev environment uses Homestead and production is Forge, so both environments should be identical (aside from the .env values).

I'm using Laravel 5.2's Authentication and have modified the register method in the the RegistersUsers.php file because I do not want to login the user right after creating a new user.  Instead, I redirect to a new route which simply shows a static view for them to check their email.  Only in production do I see the following error occur when I submit my registration form -- the error relates to the redirect to /verify.  In dev, it submits, creates a new user in the db and redirects to /verify as expected.

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

//        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));
        $this->create($request->all());

        return redirect('/verify');
//        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

This redirect is routed as follows and simply displays some static HTML:

```
Route::get('/verify', function () {return view('verify');});
```

For some strange reason, when I submit my registration form in production, the following error is returned (along with a few of the stack trace messages):

```
2016-02-23 11:23:08] production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 2542 in /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:628 Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2542): Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard->login(NULL)
#1 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController->register(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9224): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9286): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('register', Array)
#4 /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9266): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'register')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /home/forge/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /home/forge/mysite.com/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php(24): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9753): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/forge/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9743): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9267): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 /home/forge/mysite.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9254): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'register')
```

I'm no expert when it comes to swimming upstream and following this stack trace, so I'd appreciate any pointers as to how I should debug this production error.  It would appear that starting with stack trace #8, that the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware is being called and I'm not sure if this is necessary, as I am not attempting to login the user.

```
#8 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
```

Comment: Please try the following, give a name to your route in question and use `return redirect(route('routename'));`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I created a named route and verified that it worked as expected in dev, but again having the same error in production.